# htaccess - URL 'folders' always show 'folders/?link=folders'

Tags: .htaccess

I'm sorry if my question is unclear. I rewrite rule url by htaccess and it worked. So i have a problem when i try to link path of the existing folder.

My problem:

```
Redirect url: 'http://localhost/folders' 
But it display: 'http://localhost/folders/?link=folder'
```

So, I don't want it show '?link=folder'. It not show '?link=folder' with Redirect url: 'http://localhost/folders'

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?link=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?link=$1&action=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?link=$1&id=$2&action=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?link=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?link=$1&action=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ index.php?link=$1&id=$2&action=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule !^(public/*|folder/*|index\.php) [NC,F]
```

Please, someone tell me how to fix. I'm sorry if my english is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem maybe to do with the `DirectorySlash`. If "folders" is a physical directory on the filesystem and you request `http://localhost/folders` (no trailing slash) then mod_dir "fixes" the URL by 301 redirecting to `http://localhost/folders/` (with a trailing slash).

This mod_dir behaviour conflicts with the following rule that appends the `?link=folders` quesy string.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?link=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
> ```

This "rewrite" will be turned into an external "redirect" by mod_dir.

You can try preventing mod_dir from appending the trailing slash on directories with the following directive at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

However, you now need to manage all the trailing slashes yourself, which may not be trivial.

However, instead of the above, I would simply include a trailing slash on the URL to begin with and only match URLs that have the trailing slash, rather than both (you are duplicating your directives).